# context.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(model); not setting values

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working with .Net Core and EF Core and have an issue where `context.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(model);` is not setting the values.

Some items in original are null, where they are not null in the model and I would have expected that they would be updated.

I also have string values that are not being set too.

There is no error either.

When stepping through the code, there is nothing to suggest that things are going wrong.

If I were to do

`Original.Competencies = model.competencies` and then `context.SaveChangesAsync()` this works.

this is the code block in its totality.

```
using (var context = GetDbContext())
{
    var model = reportLesson.Adapt<RepositoryReportLesson>();

    var original = context.ReportLessons.Find(reportLesson.Id);
    context.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(model);
    context.Entry(original).State = EntityState.Modified;   

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    _logger.LogInformation($"->> Updated report lesson id: {id}");
    return context.Entry(model).Entity.Adapt<ReportLessonLogicModel>();
}
```

So the question is, what is causing this to not set the values, and how do I get around it?

Comment: `SetValues` does not set navigation properties. You can see which properties will be set by examining `context.Entry(original).CurrentValues.Properties` or `context.Entry(original).Properties`.

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks for the repsonse. After much time I found this out but thanks for the response.